# Django row not updating trow views.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
RefferCheck = Users.objects.get(username=str(request.POST['reffer']))
if RefferCheck:
    if empty(RefferCheck.left):
        RefferCheck.left = str(request.POST['username'])
        RefferCheck.save()
```

I am trying to update a single row in Database. but it **not working and don't show any error Too.**

**Note** :  I am not using Django forms i am using custom html forms.

Comment: What is `empty`? Can you print the `POST` data to confirm data hits the view? Also it's good python to use upper case/camelcase with class names, so `reffer_check` would be a more pythonic variable name here.

Comment: Did you ensure that your code is being fully executed and passing al conditions in there? U can try to change your `if empty(RefferCheck.left)`to `if not RefferCheck.left`and see what happens.

Comment: ```def empty(x):
 if x == "":
  return True
 else:
  return False```
and its printing POST data

Comment: Thanks @markwalker_ , `RefferCheck.left` was return `None` type. That's why my empty function did not worked. Now working well

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need this exctra check

```
RefferCheck = Users.objects.get(username=str(request.POST['reffer']))
if RefferCheck:
```

because `get()` method will raise DoesNotExists exception if no regord will be found.

Next thing is that your empty function is not needed and not working correctly. You can simply replace it with this:

```
# if left is None or empty string - this will evaluate to True
if not RefferCheck.left:
   ...
```

Comment: Not really. `RefferCheck = Users.objects.get(username=str(request.POST['reffer']))`  is checking for only the refer user registered or not

Comment: And I already comment, its working well. Thanks for your Answer

Comment: @MdJeweleIslam I still think it works in other way, here from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get)  - "If there are no results that match the query, get() will raise a DoesNotExist exception"

Comment: i used `get()` just because of the username is single. [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get)

Comment: yes, but since you're using the username that came from request - it's possible to receive not existing username and that will through the exception just because this is an idea of how `get()` works